# Undefined variable form with renderpartial

Tags: php, symfony1

I am working with symfony 1, the problem is when I put a widget in a pop up using RenderPartial function, I get the following error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: form in ...templates/template.php on line 49
>   Fatal error: Call to a member function open() on a non-object in.../templates/template.php on line 49

this is my function in class.php:

```
public function executeProduct(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  $this->renderPartial('integrate/Product');
  $form = new ProductForm();

  if ($request->isMethod('post') && $request->hasParameter($form->getName()))
  {
    $form->bindRequest($request); 
    if ($form->isValid())
    {
      $form->save();
      return $this->redirectBack();
    }
    $this->forms['product'] = $form;
  }
  else 
  {
    foreach ($form->getGlobalErrors() as $nom=>$error)
    {
      echo $nom.':'.$error;
    }
  }
}
```

what can I do as solution for that?

Comment: Can we see `templates/template.php` ?

Comment: You are not passing the $form to the view being rendered.

Comment: @TahirYasin or he just mispelled the variable name in his template (`form` instead of `forms`)

Comment: This the template.php ,  <div>
 <?php echo $form->open()?> 
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <?php echo $form['name']->field()?>
  </li>
            </ul> </div>

Comment: No,the name of the variable is correct, except this all my templates works and with the same var ($form)

Comment: @emartel how ? sorry I'm new

Comment: @jOk : with $this->form , it displays the following error Notice: Undefined property: sfPartialView::$form

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately this method is wrong, I must put `if ($request->isMethod('post'))`

I modified my template:

```
<form action="<?php echo url_for('integrate/Product') ?>" method="POST">            
<ul>
<ul> <li> <?php echo $form['name']->label()?> </li>
<?php echo $form['name']->field()?>

 </ul>
```

all blocks in  :

```
if ($request->isMethod('post') && $request->hasParameter($form->getName()))
```

if I delete that, it works but I must put it, so after this changes ; I have this error :

Notice: Undefined variable: form in ...templates/template.php on line 49
Fatal error: Call to a member function label() on a non-object in.../templates/template.php on line 49

Comment: What is the content of /templates/template.php?

Comment: @jaudette I put the content of my template

Comment: where? I need to see line 49. How come your template is named template.php and the action `executeProduct`? is this your layout?

Comment: <form action="<?php echo url_for('integrate/Product') ?>" method="POST">            
<ul>
<ul> <li> <?php echo $form['name']->label()?> </li>
<?php echo $form['name']->field()?>

 </ul> 

<ul>
<ul> <li> <?php echo $form['countit']->label()?> </li>
<?php echo $form['countit']->field()?>

 </ul> 


<?php echo $form->renderHiddenFields()?> <ul>
        <?php echo $form->renderGlobalErrors() ?>

   <div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit"
                    value="submit" /> 

</form>

Comment: If your template.php file is your layout file, you cannot access action variables from there. You need to access them from the action's template. And if it's your action's template, where do you specify it?

Answer (score 0):

When you render a partial, you have to provide the variables manually. try

```
$this->renderPartial('integrate/Product', array('form' => $form));
```

and moving the call at the end of the action.

Comment: Have you tried `return $this->renderPartial(...` at the end of your function? if not, it think it renders the standard view.